# What is the keyboard shortcut to resize text IE6?

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard-shortcuts, internet-explorer-6

What is the keyboard shortcut to resize text IE6?

Comment: Out of sheer curiosity, why are you using IE6? Newer browsers, including newer versions of Internet Explorer are faster and more secure.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it just Ctrl + Mouse wheel down?

For the cynics out there: who uses Windows without a mouse?

Edit:

> [**To change the default Internet
>   Explorer text size:**](http://www.disabled-world.com/disability/accessibility/websitedesign/text-size-internet-explorer.php)
>
> - Open the"Page"menu using your mouse or by pressing the "Alt" and "P" keys.
> - Select the "Text Size" option with your mouse or press the letter "X".
> - You can then choose your text size by clicking on it or use the up and
>     down arrow keys to select it and then
>     press the "Enter" key.
>
> If you find that the text on the
>   website hasn't changed to your new
>   text size preference it may mean the
>   website has fixed the size of their
>   web page text ('hard-coded'). If you
>   would like to use larger text on these
>   sites you will need to follow these
>   steps:
>
> - First click on the "Tools" menu at the top of Internet Explorer with the
>     mouse or press the "Alt" and "O" keys.
> - Click on "Internet Options" with your mouse button or press the letter
>     "O". You will then see "Internet
>     Options".
> - Click on the "Accessibility" button with your mouse or press the "Alt" and
>     "E" keys.
> - In the Accessibility box click "Ignore font sizes specified on web
>     page" checkbox or press your "Alt" and
>     "Z" keys.
> - Click the "OK" button to return to Internet Options.
> - Next click the "OK" button or press the "Tab" key until "OK" is
>     highlighted then press the "Enter"
>     key.
>
> **If Internet Explorer Text Sizing Doesn't Work on Some Web sites**
>
> Some Web sites are designed not to
>   resize the text even when browser
>   settings are adjusted. You can get
>   around this problem in Internet
>   Explorer Version 6 and earlier by:
>
> - Selecting - Menu items - Tools - Internet Options
> - In the Internet Options dialog box select the - Accessibility button.
> - In the Accessibility box select the following:
>
>   - Ignore colors specified on Web pages
>   - Ignore font styles specified on Web pages
>   - Ignore font sizes specified on Web pages

Comment: Control + and Control - not working on IE6

Comment: Have a look at the updated version, let me know what it does

Answer (score 0):

Do yourself a favor and use an updated browser.

But if you like IE6, here you go:
If you have a number pad: CTRL + to zoom in and CTRL - to zoom out.
if you don't CTRL SHIFT = to zoom in and CTRL SHIFT - to zoom out.

Comment: Ctrl +/Ctrl - work in other version, but not in IE6.

Unless you're bound by corporate policy, you really should update to IE8 or use Firefox or Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no shortcut for IE6 to zoom in/out. Here is the [list from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/keybrd.mspx?mfr=true). I assume you use Internet Explorer because you have to (company system with a lazy system admin I guess), but you can use the portable version of Firefox (easy to find on google, can't post 2 links).

Or if that shortcut you're looking for actually doesn't exist, an autoHotKey script (some sort of Macro scripting) may exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a combination of shortcuts. Alt + V and then "X" Enter resizes text to the largest size.

I see some websites list ALT +/- as a way to zoom, but this might only be for print preview.

Even if you can resize the text, IE may not increase the size of some websites because of the way some sites code their pages.